# Python+openpyxlで作成したxlsxファイルが文字化けする。

Tags: excel, openpyxl

openpyxlを使用したExcel自動入力アプリを作成したのですが、作成されたxlsxファイルをExcel365(Windows)で開くと、文字化けします（#になる）。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
原因を色々と探り、フォントが問題（Droid Sans Fallback）なのかと思い、游ゴシックで入力されるようにソースコードを書き換えてみましたが、それでも文字化けは残っていました。
他に、文字数が一定を超えると文字化けする等書かれた記事も見つけましたが、１つのセルに対して２〜４文字までしか入力していません。

openpyxlで作成後のファイルを、Excelの書式設定で分類を違うものに一度変えてやると解消できるのですが（入力時の分類は数値）、毎回その作業を行うのは面倒なので、文字化けしないファイルを作成できるようにしたいです。良い解決方法がございましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

単に列幅が狭くて表示できない時に [##### と表示された](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/-%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E4%BF%AE%E6%AD%A3%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95-bf801d0a-2a6e-44bd-a70e-0f780ae8f11e)だけではありませんか？ そうであれば、列幅を広くしてください。

Comment: 参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @daniel_27899 ありがとうコメントは不要です。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) に沿って回答の承認をお願いします。